How to prevent chat() function in pandasai from downloading images?
I'm using the pandasai library for data analysis in my application. When I call the chat() function to generate image responses, it triggers a download of the images instead of displaying them. I want to display these images directly in my application.
Here’s a snippet of my code:
import pandas as pd
from pandasai import SmartDataframe
from langchain_groq.chat_models import ChatGroq
import os
import streamlit as st

# groq
llm = ChatGroq(model_name="llama3-70b-8192", api_key=os.environ["GROQ_API_KEY"])

# Streamlit app setup
st.title("Data Analysis with SmartDataframe")

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
df = SmartDataframe(df, config={"llm": llm})

st.write("Smart Dataframe")

# User input for chat command
user_input = st.text_input("Enter your command:")

if user_input:  # Check if user input is provided
    response = df.chat(user_input)  # # This line triggers the download
    # Assuming response is an image URL or path
    st.image(response, use_container_width=True)

The issue arises when I call response = df.chat(user_input), which seems to trigger a download of the image instead of displaying it. I expected the image to be shown directly in my application.
Is there a way to modify the chat() function in pandasai to prevent this download behaviour? If not, I would appreciate any guidance on how to implement this feature or any workarounds to display the image directly.
